# Find All Values of a so that |A|=0.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I solved this problem by getting the determinant, and I ended up using the quadratic formula. However, it seems my solution is incorrect, and I've done it multiple times to make sure I didn't make a mistake. Please, if you have any hints or tips, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I imagine you're making a mistake when doing your Laplace expansion.  You should be getting $|A| =-10a^2-42a+416$.  Remember that you can also use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) for $3\times 3$ determinants if that's easier for you.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of uploading an image of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know.